# mssql: add column with the same value for all rows to search results

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have my query:

```
    SELECT [Shipment Date], [Amount] as [Running Costs], Sum([Amount]) OVER 
    (ORDER BY [Shipment Date]) as [Total Running Costs]
    FROM...
```

This gets me 3 columns:

`Shipment Date | Running Costs | Total Running Costs`

I would like to add a fourth column to this query which has the same value for all rows, and the same number of rows as my original query results.

I know you could add for example '999'as Something to the search results, but how can I do the same for a sum of another column (example: Imagine the total sum of the a column in another table is 1500, and I want to have 1500 for all rows in the fourth column. Something like select sum(column_name)?

The database engine is MSSQL.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would make it easier to assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested query

```
SELECT [Shipment Date], [Amount] as [Running Costs], [Total Running Costs], SUM([Total Running Costs] OVER ())  
FROM  
(  
 SELECT [Shipment Date], [Amount] as [Running Costs], Sum([Amount]) OVER   
 (ORDER BY [Shipment Date]) as [Total Running Costs]  
 FROM...  
)
```

Nested window function should also work

```
SUM(SUM([Running costs]) OVER (ORDER BY [Shipment Date])) OVER ()
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to sum a column of another table actually, not the same one

Comment: I also the error "is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." if I try it this way